# How to display GPS data in richTextBox with no empty line between in Real-Time program?

Tags: textbox, gps, serial-port, richtextbox, nmea

Helou, I find program which display raw NMEA data fromy gps by port COM in Real-Time. LInks here: http://csharp.simpleserial.com/ . I do a little modification, and I added richTextBox because I needed it to my part of GPS program (in originaly is only TextBox). Then I connect my GPS and ... :

My **problem/question**: is any way to **display raw nmea** data in **richTextBox** which **no empty lines**? My problems shows in the picture below. Please help.

[image: empty_line_inside_rtb]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the answer, I added to code:

```
private void rtb1_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        // if lines dont starts with char $ dont display it
        var lines = rtb1.Lines.Where(l => l.StartsWith("$"));
        rtb1.Text = String.Join("\n", lines);
    }
```

But is it correct and only way to solve this problem?

I test this part and it's not correct in displaying data .. Sometimes it's added for example in one line "$GPRMC,,,..$GPGSV" ..